# ParamQuery get parent row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, paramquery

If I have the rowIndx of a row inside a detail grid, how can I get its parent row in the main grid?
See the image please:
the row with the data {1,test} has the parent row with ID CLN00742. How I can get this row?

[image: My Grid]

I went through the API and the docs and found no solution, also I searched their forum.

Comment: Can you add html? You can try with `var parentTr = $(currentTr).closest('tr')`.

Comment: It is a javascript grid

Comment: It is returning the same row!

Comment: Try var parentTr = $(currentTr).closest('tr').closest('tr');